# Php MySql Query does not return a result

Tags: php, mysql

Situation : var $No is local on php file, and is posted as item_number in my db whenever the Ipn returns 'Complete', after Buy button is cliked and buying process finished. This part works.

On original form I need to retreived "payment_amt" value corresponding to unique item_number.
var $No is produced on original order page (here).

The code below does not return any value nor error messages (db is connected though, and data is recorded)

```
include_once('../connect.php');
$Amount = mysql_query("SELECT payment_amt FROM al_paypal WHERE 
item_number='" .$No . "'");

$query = mysql_query($Amount);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
$My_Amount = $row[0];

echo $My_Amount;
echo mysql_error();
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you know there are no error messages? You don't check for them.

Comment: Where is `$No` coming from? You've included (*some form of explanation*) on top, but it's not known how you're using it.

Comment: Are you sure that $No is being passed in, and it actually matches a record in the DB?

Comment: Yes $No is passed on (If I echo it, it shows). Yes I checked if it is present (very same one) in db, and it is.

Comment: I thought : echo mysql_error(); would check for MySQL errors

Comment: We need to **see** the actual code where `$No` is being populated from. If it's coming from a form or a GET/href method, then show that also. Otherwise, we can't help you.

Comment: We also need to know if $No matches exactly.  You are calling it as a string.  If the field is 1 and you're passing in "01", it's not the same thing.

Comment: Another thing to be aware of is that `$No` is not the same as `$no` @user3371049

Comment: I am aware of all of the above, I checked everything  before I posted my message here. So I guess my Query is good, since nobody commented on it. Thats a good point, at least.

Comment: We're just trying to help find a solution for you. At this point, if you say everything is good and double checked, then re-check what your column types are, if they're the right length, etc. It could be a missing dot, a comma... it could be anything. Also check to see if you need to pass DB connection to your query.

Comment: What value is supposed to be going/passed through the `$No` variable? Is it text, a number, a comma-seperated value, an array, other?

Comment: When the var $No is posted via Paypal IPN, I get it properly in my Database: W1-40430-1412-07570 <-- unique ID number for my product. It is the retrieval part that is problematic. If I copy "W1-40430-1412-07570" directly in my Query (above) instead of the var. Same: no results.

Comment: See my answer below. @user3371049 I figured it out.

Comment: You realize you're querying a query result right?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're querying twice when using `mysql_query()`

```
$Amount = mysql_query("SELECT payment_amt FROM al_paypal WHERE item_number='" .$No . "'");
```

along with:

```
$query = mysql_query($Amount);
```

Change it to: (by removing `mysql_query`)

```
$Amount = "SELECT payment_amt FROM al_paypal WHERE item_number='" .$No . "'";
```

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

- **http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php**

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Comment: You're welcome @user3371049 Was glad to have been of help.

Comment: Please tick the checkmark next to my answer till it turns Green to close the question and be marked as answered. @user3371049 that's how the StackOverflow system works.

Comment: @user3371049 Be sure to select this answer as the correct one if it solved your problem.

Comment: Just did @JohnConde, tx for the reminder.

Comment: @user3371049 Easy two rep points for you =)

Comment: OP's gonna love those @JohnConde